# My POST API route has a delayed execution?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

**Whats the Problem?**

The code below inserts a team into the Team table but stops there
   and doesn't proceed as if the team is not created quick enough (i think). Which results in the next query not finding the team and not executing the insert query in the second if statement.

However , After I go to a different page which executes a different function within the API, POST Register executes again as i feel that its because i have no catch but also it then finds the team and adds the user into TeamUsers Table but this is to slow.

```
const findTeam = await Team.findOne({
          where: {
            inviteCode: teamData.inviteCode
          }
        });
```

Below is my API ROUTE which starts by retrieving data from the users record and the current websites form.

```
// --- Register Team ---
    router.post('/registerTeam', auth, async function(req, res) {
      //Get Auth UserID for FK in Teams Table
      const users = req.user.id;
      const today = new Date();
      const teamData = {
        UserID: users,
        TeamName: req.body.TeamName,
        League: req.body.League,
        inviteCode: req.body.inviteCode,
        createdAt: today,
        updatedAt: today
      };

      //Create Team   -- Working
      const team = new Team(teamData);

      team.save();
      if (team) {
        //Find the Team
        const findTeam = await Team.findOne({
          where: {
            inviteCode: teamData.inviteCode
          }
        });

        //IF team is found
        if (findTeam) {
          // Obtain Auths User Data for the TeamUsers Table Record
          const userData = {
            UserID: req.user.id,
            TeamID: findTeam.id,
            createdAt: today,
            updatedAt: today
          };

          const teamUser = new TeamUsers(userData);
          teamUser.save();
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried adding await before `team.save();` like so: `await team.save();` ?

Comment: @Mohdule Thats worked!! If u want to submit an answer , I will happily approve it !

Comment: you are welcome :),  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are missing an `await` before the `team.save();`

like so :
`await team.save();`